# Mouse scroll in VLC fast forward and increase volume in the same time

Tags: vlc-media-player

I encounter a weird issue with recent VLC version and I am not able to find information about this problem.

When I scroll using the mouse wheel during a video, it fast forward the video *and* increase the volume in the same time it  (reciprocally rewind and decrease volume).

Before < some update > the scroll simply decreased and increased volume.

When I go in **Preferences** >  **Hotkeys** there no mention of mouse wheel.

I am probably missing something obvious but anyone know where I can find the option to correct this problem ?

[image: vlc hotkeys screenshot]

Comment: Is the volume control focused?  If it is your scrolling action may be affecting the volume slider also.

Comment: No it happen when the cursor is on the video.

Comment: Can you provide more details to the OS, build, and installation method?  Will have to try to replicate the issue.

Comment: On Windows and Ubuntu using the touchpad...

Comment: How is the "mouse wheel scroll" configured?  Touchpads don't have "normal" mouse wheels and it may be captured incorrectly as something else.

I use something called "Autohotkey" and it has a feature that tells me exactly what the computer sees my "mouse scroll" as, but I think the details are too much for a comment.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you mean but I use two-finger to scroll

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you report the bug?

Comment: Login as a different user and see if the problem persists. If it doesn't, you'll know the problem is in the configuration and not in VLC itself.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Gestures then you can use Click (and hold mouse button) and move slightly right to skip 10 seconds, click (hold) and left to skip backwards 10 seconds.

The 10 second skip CAN be altered in the Hotkey Settings > Short Jump Length > enter required skip length.

(how to enable Gestures - https://www.vlchelp.com/how-to-use-mouse-gestures/ )

You're all welcome :)

[EDIT]

My mistake, I was searching for a fix for the crappy 'new' video scan with mousewheel so must of got confused.
As to OPs issue, no real idea but after a quick search, I can't find anyone else that is having this issue.

Only thing I can think is that with newer versions (3.0.1) then on the Configure Hotkeys menu, there is a pair of options, one to define both horizontal and vertical axis of VLC (vertical / volume and horizontal / seek) for mousewheel, unlike the version shown only seems to have 1 axis option (at the bottom of the screenshot).

As an interim 'fix', Gestures can be used, while not as convenient as mousewheel, it should work.

Click + Up / Down = Volume Up / Down in 5% increments.

Comment: I believe the point of the question is how to adjust the volume (with the mouse wheel) *without* affecting the timing (ff/rew) of the video.  Can you answer that?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.